# Can't append html to div parent with jquery and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, append, marionette

I'm using Backbone marionnete too create some views.
Now I need to perform a ajax call to my backend. To make the user clear I perfoming an action I want to show a spinner. My eye felt on this one: [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) Now before I trigger my ajax call I want to append the spinner to my parent. Therefore I though to use plain jquery and append the el like this

```
callBackend: ->
  spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
  $('.model-content').append(spinner.el);
```

Now I noticed nothing get's added to to dom. But when I perfom the same command in the browser terminal using debugger so the same spinner instance it draws nicely on the screen. So I know for some reason `$('.model-content').append(spinner.el);` is behaving like it should. Some body any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if your forgot something in your code, but maybe you just need to define it: `spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();` ?

Comment: Where do you define what `spinner` is? You never save the result from `new Spinner(opts).spin();`. The example form the documentation is `var spinner = new Spinner().spin();`

Comment: I do assign the spinner to a var, forgot to mention it in my post, will update it

Comment: Are you certain that `$('.model-content')` finds something? When and how is `callBackend` getting called?

Comment: Yes check that $('.model-content') returned something and spinner.el also. Used console.log to verify this

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I would guess it has something to do with what you're passing into your spinner.  If you are passing in 'opts' remove it. Otherwise, make sure you're passing in an object of options.

Try

```
spinner = new Spinner().spin();
```

or

```
opts = { color: '#000', width: 10 }
spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
```